# How do I get Geany back to windowed

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, geany

I have Geany in full screen on my rpi. There is no frame, with minimize or windowed buttons on the screen.I read where this is a java problem. I want to use Geany in the windowed mode. How do I get there or is it even possible?
Jim

Comment: ftr, there is a RPi StackExchange.  I can tell you right off that this isn't nearly enough information to solve the problem, though.

Answer (score 2):

Press F11 to close the fullsize mode.